# ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I have a maven-based app that I copied exactly and tried to run `mvn jetty:run`

And now getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 47 more
```

The weird thing is the same exact copy of the project that works on the other machine.

Here are the complete dependencies:

        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fastjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>boon</artifactId>
            <version>0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jee</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${version.restlet}</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.swagger</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.raml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>raml-parser</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.xstream</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.3m</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.carlosbecker</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-junit-test-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
            <artifactId>xodus-openAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
            <artifactId>xodus-environment</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
            <artifactId>xodus-entity-store</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fluttercode.datafactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>datafactory</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>`

Comment: I believe `javax.servlet:servlet-api` must be `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: I changed it to `<scope>provided</scope>` just now and the same error persists

Comment: What does the `<plugin>` section for your `jetty-maven-plugin` look like?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the class `javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory` does not exist in `servlet-api` artifact. It exists in `jsp-api` artifact. I exploded the 2 jars and here's the result:

[image]

Add the jsp-api dependency according to the version you need, e.g.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still does not fix the same issue even adding this

Comment: have you run `mvn clean` after adding new artifact?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

tomcat-embed-jasper: provides support for .jsp file rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I added both the dependencies from both the previous answers and removed the dependency that I added from the maven repository. Copying both dependencies so it won't create any confusion after some more answers are added.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```